# How do I restore an account that was not deleted?

Tags: macos, user-account, data-recovery

I recently had to reboot my computer, and when it finished booting my account was gone (it was not showing in the log in screen)! I got onto the admin account and found that although the user was not deleted, there are a lot of red minus signs:

[image]

How do I fix this?

I noticed that it does not work quite like what is described here:
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22002?locale=en_US

It's more like this:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4171806?start=0&tstart=0

I am running OS X El Capitan 10.11.3

Answer (score 1):

Log-in as admin user and open Terminal. Then enter

```
sudo dscl . read /Users/lost_username
```

Replace lost_username by the short name of the "hidden" or "lost" user.

If the user is still there check if the account is hidden:

```
sudo dscl . read /Users/lost_username IsHidden
```

If you get the following response: *No such key: IsHidden* you have a real problem. If it yields: *dsAttrTypeNative:IsHidden: 1* your user is just hidden.

Unhide your user with:

```
sudo dscl . create /Users/lost_username IsHidden 0
```

or delete the key with

```
sudo dscl . delete /Users/lost_username IsHidden
```

You have to reboot after entering either of the last two commands to unhide the account.

---

If you get  *DS Error: -14136 (eDSRecordNotFound)* after entering the first command your user was deleted in the directory nodes.

**Quick and dirty fix:**

List the users' UniqueIDs with:

```
dscl . -list /Users UniqueID
```

Usually the first account created after installing OS X gets the 501, the second 502 and so on. Check for gaps (e.g. 502 is missing).

Rename (shorten) the abandoned user folder. Create a new user with the old user name (lost_username) and the old password. Check the UniqueID of the new user:

```
sudo dscl . -read /Users/lost_username UniqueID
```

Compare this UniqueID with the missing one. If they aren't the same, change the UniqueID of the newly created user to the missing one:

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/lost_username UniqueID 502 #choose the missing ID here
```

Remove the newly created user folder (with the name lost_username). Rename the previously renamed (old and full with data) user folder to lost_username.

Log-in as lost_username.